# Is "Bluedroid" used for android bluetooth class protocol stack?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluez

I’m trying to achieve serial communication using android's bluetooth class.（BluetoothAdapter, BluetoothSocket, etc）
I understand that this class uses "Bluedroid" behind, Is this understanding correct?
Also, is it possible to use "BlueZ" as a native library(NDK)?
I think possible because it is like creating a new class for bluetooth.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why do you care what's used at a lower level as long as it works?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan  For some time now, others have been developing using "BlueZ" on Linux terminals.  We are planning to migrate from linux to Android.  However, for company reasons, they want to continue to use "BlueZ" library.  So I'd like to know how the lower level work.